# Which HTTP authentication scheme does Jenkins use?

Tags: jenkins, http-authentication

I'm trying to send HTTP requests to a Jenkins server which requires authentication, which authentication scheme do I need to use? cURL seems to figure it out automatically, FWIW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like Jenkins is using [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients).

Comment: Thanks! I also learnt that I can now send a token rather than the password itself, which worried me with Basic auth!

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTP BASIC authentication to authenticate remote API requests. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients